# Finding Camera Matrix from known Points python

Tags: python, computer-vision, camera-calibration

I have 8 3d points of a 3D model and 8 2d points of that model's real world photograph. is it possible to get the camera matrix of that camera using these 3D and 2D points?

here are the 3D points

```
      X       Y        Z
0   0.098   35.484   16.58
1   17.34   38.638   16.28
2   27.65   44.133   0.083
3   17.23   38.678  -16.25
4   0.068   35.536  -16.58
5  -17.24   38.799  -16.06
6  -27.67   44.402   0.379
7  -17.10   38.820   16.21
```

here are the 2D points

```
      X      Y   
0    777    203
1   1015    217
2   1142    440
3   1019    662
4    778    675
5    542    660
6    425    442
7    546    219
```

what would be the camera matrix for this scenario and How can I get it using python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the problem of estimating the camera matrix given 3D points and their projection is called **Camera resectioning**. You need at least 6 points to be able to solve it.
In Python you can use OpenCV's `calibrateCamera` function:

```
retval, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objectPoints, imagePoints, imageSize)
```

For a more in-depth explanation of the camera resection problem, you can read [here](https://canvas.education.lu.se/courses/3379/files/213436/download?download_frd=1), section 3.1.

EDIT: the 3d points should be in planar so that 3D points' z coordinates should be 0.0  . In order to do that you need to put the 3d dots on real object on z plane

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am using this function but it requires camera matrix. it says 'calibrateCamera() missing required argument 'cameraMatrix''  even I put it as None it still asks for camera matrix

Comment: Does your image have proper EXIF data? You can construct a camera intrinsics matrix with focal points, and principal points (that are usually half the image size).

Comment: I did that actually. I have put the matrix with focal points and principal points. The functions changes it as output but the result is not the right one. Because I have the correct matrix that I have calculated using chessboard. I guess I need to use planar points as the link mentions https://answers.opencv.org/question/193188/calibration-from-points-instead-of-chessboard/

Comment: I also found [this nice library](https://github.com/wingedrasengan927/Image-formation-and-camera-calibration/blob/master/utils.py) that has implemented the in-depth explanation I cited above. There is a nice Jupyter notebook that has gone through it step by step. **Perform Direct Linear Calibration** part in [this notebook](https://gist.github.com/wingedrasengan927/5bf68be5837b0294ab7fbc225009f1bc#file-camera-calibration-medium-ipynb) is for you, and M is the projection matrix.

Comment: Thanks ara, I will check that out and I will notify you if I make it working

Comment: Hi ara, I have tried the algorithm in your link but I couldnt make it work. Actually it worked but the result didnt make sense to me. May be I did something wrong. Then I tried the cv method again. when I put the 3d real dots in a planar area ( so I was able to make the z coordinates 0.0) then the above cv2 algorithm works and give me the matrix. It is not the same with the one I got using checkboard but it is close. Also it looks so fragile. it changes even in small point changes. I will check the result with different photos. Thanks for your help and directions ara, deeply appreciated  : )